# What is the song that plays in Naruto Shippuden's first episode during Sasuke's first appearance?

Tags: naruto, music

In the very first episode of Naruto Shippuden at the start when we see Sasuke, what is the song that plays here?

Comment: you'll possibly find them in the ost's listen to loneliness i think that is the same

Answer (score 1):

The title of the track you are looking for is [Shippuu Kumikyoku (Hurricane Suite)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5Hp42y7gVA&index=28&list=PL4C928EAF7AA5B906). This track is on Naruto Shippuden OST 1, Track 28

Answer (score -1):

Hero's come back by Nobody knows. Its the very first op of shippuden

Comment: Could you add a link to the music you are referring to?

Comment: [Hero's come back](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hero%27s_Come_Back!!) is the title of first opening to Shippuden. OP is requesting the title of the first time Sasuke appears